# ZeroMQ-terminate called after throwing an instance of 'zmq::error_t' socket operation on non socket when using poll() function on c++

Tags: c++, zeromq

Hi I'm trying to use a **`poll()`** function from the **`ZeroMQ`** library on the server side.

In fact I want to receive notifications from my clients in order to execute a script in my code.

I found that link
[using zmq::poll in multithreaded c++0x11 program in combination with cntr +x or kill signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935202/using-zmqpoll-in-multithreaded-c0x11-program-in-combination-with-cntr-x-or)

It throws an instance of **`zmq::error_t` socket operation on non socket**

It seems not to be working for me!

Comment: This code is far from a StackOverflow **promoted MCVE method** of posting the high quality Questions. Text states (cit.:) "... on server side. ... my clients ... It seems ... ." **Update your Question to contain a fully representative MCVE for both the server & client** that can reproduce the problem you are reporting and asking the Community to help diagnose and fix. **This is the StackOverflow preferred way** to constructively solve and discuss any kind of MCVE related issues. Anyway, **welcome to this great Community of knowledge** and feel free to contribute in our way forwards.

Comment: I suspect there's an easy fix - just fix the code and it will work as expected. (aka, please show some code)

Comment: Regardless, error messages should be clear, and should not require code context to see them.