# Exception handling in a pub-sub scheme (ZeroMQ)

Tags: c, error-handling, zeromq

I've created a publisher-subscriber communication scheme with ZeroMQ and I noticed one small issue with my server and client programs.
I know there is no try catch in C (according to my brief research) however having the next two `while(1)` without an exception catching seems dangerous to me.

Taking into account the following code snippets, what would be the most correct way to handle an exception (inside the while)? With the structure I have right now (as you can see below), the `zmq_close` and `zmq_ctx_destroy` will never execute, but I want them to, in case of a program error/exception (whichever the origin).

**Note:** In this architecture I have one client listening to multiple publishers, thus the `for` cycles in the **Client** code.

**Server**

```
(...inside main)

while (1) {
    char update[20];
    sprintf(update, "%s", "new_update");
    s_send(publisher, update);
    sleep(1);
}

zmq_close(publisher);
zmq_ctx_destroy(context);
return 0;
```

**Client**

```
(...inside main)

while(1){
    for (c = 1; c < server_num; c = c + 1){
        char *msg = s_recv(subscribers[c]);

        if (msg) {
            printf("%s\n",msg);
            free(msg);
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
}

for (c = 0; c < server_num; c = c + 1)
    zmq_close(subscribers[c]);

zmq_ctx_destroy(context);
return 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being the tag [error-handling](/questions/tagged/error-handling) present:

> **Q** : *what would be the most correct way to handle an exception (inside the while)?*

**The best strategy** is an ***error-prevention*** rather than ***any** kind* of "reactive" ( ex-post Exception ) handling.

Always assume the things may and will turn wreck havoc and let them fail cheaply. The cheaper the costs of failings are, the better and sooner the system may turn back into its own, intended behaviour.

This said, in modern low-latency distributed-systems, the more in real-time-systems an exception is extremely expensive, disruptive element of the designed code-execution flow.

---

### <sub>For these reasons, and for allowing sustained levels of the utmost performance too,</sub>
ZeroMQ has since ever a very different approach :

**0)**
better use **`zmq_poll()`** as a **cheapest ever detection** of a presence ( or not presence ) of any read-able message ( already delivered and being ready so as to be received ), before ever, if at all, calling an API function of a `zmq_recv()`, to fetch such data into your application-level code's hands, from inside the `Context()`-instance internal storage.

**1)**
depending on your language binding (wrapper), best enjoy the **non-blocking forms** of the `.poll()`, `.send()` and `.recv()` methods. The native API is the most straightforward in always going in this mode with **`retCode = zmq_recv( ..., ZMQ_NOBLOCK );`**

**2)**
**Always analyse** the **`retCode`** - be it in a silent or explanatory `assert( retCode == 0 && zmq_errno() )` or otherwise.

**3)**
Best review and **fine-tune all configuration attributes** of the instantiated tools available from ZeroMQ framework and harness all their hidden strengths to best match your application domain's needs. Many native API-settings may help mitigate, if not principally avoid, lots of colliding requirements right inside the `Context()`-engine instance, so do not hesitate to learn all details of possible settings and use them to the best of their help for your code.

Without doing all of this above, your code is **not** making the best of the **Zen-of-Zero**

---

> **Q** : *With the structure I have right now (...), the `zmq_close` and `zmq_ctx_destroy` will never execute, but I want them to, in case of a program error/exception (whichever the origin).*

it is fair enough to set an explicit flag:

```
bool    DoNotExitSoFar = True;

while ( DoNotExitSoFar ){
    // Do whatever you need

    // Record return-codes, always
       retCode = zmq_...(...);

    // Test/Set the explicit flag upon a context of retCode and zmq_errno()
       if ( retCode == EPROTONOTSUPPORTED ){
         // take all due measures needed
            ...
         // FINALLY: Set
            DoNotExitSoFar = False;
       }
}

// --------------------------------------------- GRACEFUL TERMINATION .close()
if ( ENOTSOCK == zmq_close(...) ) { ...; }
...
// --------------------------------------------- GRACEFUL TERMINATION .term()
retCode = zmq_ctx_term(...);

if ( EINTR  == retCode ){ ...; }
if ( EFAULT == retCode ){ ...; }
...
```

---

Using other tooling, like `int atexit(void (*func)(void));` may serve as the last resort for a ALAP calling `zmq_close()` or `zmq_ctx_term()`

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way in C to check for error is to look the return value and then check errno if it's negative.

```
// ... Your previous code
int ret = zmq_ctx_destroy(context);
if(ret < 0) {
    // Process your error here
    printf("My error message is : %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
```

You may need to add `#include <errno.h>` and `<string.h>` if it's not already in your program.
You can also read [strerror](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror) documentation.

Now to adress this part of the question :

> Taking into account the following code snippets, what would be the most correct way to handle an exception (inside the while)? With the structure I have right now (as you can see below), the zmq_close and zmq_ctx_destroy will never execute, but I want them to, in case of a program error/exception (whichever the origin).

All `zmq_*` functions will return an error and set errno. Check every function and `break` when an error occur. In that scenario, polling on non-blocking function is best to `break` out of your `while`loop when an error occurs.

On Linux, you can also set a signal handler and execute a clean up routine when a singal is raised (for example, it is very common to catch SIGINT to properly exit a program on UNIX on ctrl+C in the console).  See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55508391/zeromq-handling-interrupt-in-multithreaded-application/55512521#55512521)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, C has no concept of try/catch, but that shouldn't be an issue.  It just means you need to handle exceptions in the s_send() and s_recv() routines (so, for example, if something unexpected happens (like malloc() returning NULL), you have to deal with it and continue processing or return).

I would also suggest you look at the poll() or select() system calls for your client instead of doing a looping poll.  It's much more elegant to only service the file descriptors that have data waiting to be read.